# Adding more than one song to single AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app i am using AVAudioPlayer. Is it possible to add more number of songs to single AVAudioPlayer. Any one can help or sugget with links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to use [`AVQueuePlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010168) instead.